# Using protobuf-net with inheritance and interface

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I have a proto contract as follows:

```
[ProtoContract]
public MyContract: ContractBase
{
   [ProtoMember(1)] 
   List<IMyDto> MyData
  {
      get;
     set;
  }
}
```

My IMyDto looks like this and its implemenation MyDto

```
[ProtoInclude(600, typeof(MyDto))]
public interface IMyDto
{
   int MyData
   {
    get;
    set;
   }
}
[ProtoContract]
public class MyDto :IMyDto
{
   [ProtoMember(1)]
   int MyData
   {
    get;
    set;
   }
}
```

Finally, my ContractBase looks like this:

```
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(500, typeof(MyContract))]
public class ContractBase
{
   [ProtoMember(501)]
   public string[] ErrorMessages
   {
     get;
     set;
   }
 }
```

When I make the web service call, I keep getting the following error:

**It was not possible to prepare a serializer for: ContractBase ---> System.InvalidOperationException: No serializer defined for type: IMyDto**

Please note that this is a simplified version of code for understanding the problem.

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong? 
Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mark `IMyDto` with `[ProtoContract]` attribute.
It worked for me, after I've done that.
[Getting Started documentation](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/wiki/GettingStarted) says, it is necessary every type participating in serialization is marked so.